# Selenium fails to initiate Firefox WebDriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, automated-tests

I get an error while trying to initiate the WebDriver:

```
package Web.Utils;

import Web.Utils.WebConfig;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.FirefoxDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
// Import the necessary libraries
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BrowserUtil {
    public static WebDriver createBrowser(){
        return createBrowser(WebConfig.getDefaultBrowser());
    }
    public static WebDriver createBrowser(String browserType){
        WebDriver driver;
        switch (browserType) {
            case "chrome" -> {
                ChromeDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            case "firefox" -> {
                FirefoxDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            default -> throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported browser");
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }
}
```

This is the error message I receive:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService, java.util.Map)'
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.(FirefoxDriver.java:340)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
> at Web.Utils.BrowserUtil.createBrowser(BrowserUtil.java:27)
> at Web.Utils.BrowserUtil.createBrowser(BrowserUtil.java:16)
> at Btube.Web.PageObjects.Shared.AllPages.(AllPages.java:30)
> at Web.Hooks.DefaultHooks.setup(DefaultHooks.java:22)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
> at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
> at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
> at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
> at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:372)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
> at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
> at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Because of this error message I'm not able to run my tests. I think it might have to do with the dependancies not working correctly with eachother, but there doesn't seem to be an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_Framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
            <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>com.google.guava</groupId><artifactId>guava</artifactId><version>31.1-jre</version></dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried changing the versions of the dependancies, but it didn't change the error. I also tried specifing the gecko web driver while initiating the webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the issue.

The problem was, as expected, in the pom.xml.

It does seem to work with these dependancy versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_Framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
            <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><groupId>com.google.guava</groupId><artifactId>guava</artifactId><version>31.1-jre</version></dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```